# How can MovingAverage be used for the solution of nd solve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, difference-equations

The code I used is as below but it doesn't work. Is there anyone who could understand and solve the problem? I want to plot d instead of s.Also, How can I fit a linear function to the d'.

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
d=MovingAverage[s, 10];
Plot[d, {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: `NDSolve` returns an interpolating function, which is continuous. How do you want to average successive 10 points from a continuous curve? // You could sample `s` to get `List` of values and run `MovingAverage` on this list.

Comment: What do you mean by sampling s? @corey979

Comment: You mean there isn't any way to calculate meanaverage of continues function? @corey979

Comment: @OliverRange Moving average is calculated from a list of values, this function requires you to explicitly give those.

Comment: The continuous equivalent of "moving average" is called convolution.  But here, since everything is numeric, it's better to sample discrete values and work with those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the actual `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
s = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
```

Generate the moving average of a list of the values from this `ip`:

```
d = MovingAverage[Table[{i, s[i]}, {i, 0, 30, 0.1}], 10];
```

Plot:

```
Show[Plot[s[t], {t, 0, 30}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ListLinePlot[d, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]

You can reform this moving average into an `InterpolatinFunction`.

```
ip = Interpolation[d];
Plot[{ip[x], ip'[x]}, {x, 0.45, 29.6}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to plot slop of the d? I used this code but it didn't work:   Plot[d'[t], {t, 0, 30}]

Comment: @OliverRange check the edit.

Comment: You could use `NDSolveValue` in stead of the part extraction.

Comment: I did post this as community wiki ;) @user21